# Replacing XML node key using dataprovider karate

Tags: karate

I am reading my xml structure from a file and replacing the values from the examples

- def inputXml = read('classpath:xml/input.xml')

  My xml structure is like below

```
 <input>
 <data>
 <props>
 <p n="AMOUNT">1000</p>
 <p n="NAME">name</p>
 <p n="{ACCOUNTTYPE}">purpose</p>
 </props>
 </data>
 </input>
```

I am driving data from examples and setting/replacing the input xml as below

```
* set inputXml/input/data/props/p[@n='AMOUNT'] = <AMOUNT> -- Works fine
* set inputXml/input/data/props/p[@n='NAME'] = <NAME> -- Works fine
```

Examples:

```
|AMOUNT|NAME|ACCOUNTTYPE|PURPOSE|



|100|abc|BUSINESS|smallbusiness|



|2000|def|PERSONAL|home|
```

I want to update the "n" tag name ACCOUNTTYPE and corresponsding PURPOSE similar to above(both key and value). Is there a way to achieve this in Karate? Please suggest.

Is is possible to use '#(accountType)' and '#(purpose)' inside the xml file similar to json and run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is possible to use '#(accountType)' and '#(purpose)' inside the xml file

Yes. Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

And the examples: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

```
Given def user = <user><name>john</name></user>
And def lang = 'en'
When def session = <session><locale>#(lang)</locale><sessionUser>#(user)</sessionUser></session>
```